# Equivilant of $MODULE_DIR$ in unix terminals

Tags: unix, intellij-idea, debian

I am trying to run a programme on a debain dedi. Using the following code.

```
 java -cp bin:lib/* rs.Server false 43594
```

However it gives me a file not found error (even though the files are present). I fixed this error in intellij by picking the $MODULE_DIR$ option. Is there a equivalent to this in unix terminals?

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks to be that the directory your are in when you run the command is wrong. You either need to cd to the directory containing the bin and lib directories or specify the full path to the directories in the command line.

Comment: The O.P. may also need to specify current dir i.e. `./rs.Server`. Good luck.